# How to get Service Worker working on Chrome Lighthouse?

Tags: lighthouse

I am trying to audit my application on Chrome Lighthouse, but I can't get Service Worker working. It is registered and running with no error, but when I try to run Lighthouse it gets stuck and console log the fallowing error:

```
Service worker not registered  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://www.localhost.com/') with script ('https://www.localhost.com/sw.js'): Operation has been aborted
```

SW is called with:

```
    if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    let sw = 'sw.js';
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(sw, {scope: "/"})
        .then(function(){
            console.log('Service worker registered.');
        })
        .catch(function(e){
            console.log('Service worker not registered ', e);
        })
}
```

In the manifest:

```
start_url: "/",
    scope: "/",
```

I also tried:

"../",
"https://www.localhost.com/",
"./",

I am running chrome with the flags:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://www.localhost.com
```

But, I also tried to run the application in a remote server with https and I got the same error.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Looks like Chrome v 95 has some issues with Service Workers lighthouse testing
See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13236

Comment: Thanks, I found out that If I uncheck the clear cache option in lighthouse options it starts working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I uncheck the clear cache option in lighthouse options it starts working.

Edit: As mentioned by Sean McCarthy below the correct name is "Clear storage"

Comment: Same here except for me it's called "Clear storage". [This GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13236#issuecomment-959888243) showed me where to do it. 

Comment: If you're still wondering, where the option is, there is a settings button towards the right of the window, which will expand this for you. Still not working? Do this in Incognito mode and it should.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Clear storage" seems also to work